# How to parse a string of a javascript object (not valid JSON) for keys only

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I am trying to convert a string that is a JS object to valid json. This involves adding quotes to the key.

This works:

```
/([\w]+)(:)/g
```

(I am actually doing this with replace)

```
str.replace((/([\w]+)(:)/g), "\"$1\"$2")
```

Except it matches any word that has a `:` even in the value.

Example:

```
"{ 
  key1: "Value 1",
  key2: "http://dummyimage.com/600x400/7190d6/fff.png"
 }"
```

this matches `key1:`, `key2`, and `http:`

I only want to match `key1:` and `key2`

Of course, I apologize if this has been answered. I have been looking for quite some time to no avail.

If I could work with valid JSON in the first place obviously that would be great but unfortunately that is out of my control.

Comment: `str = JSON.stringify(obj);` does what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a positive look ahead.  For example:

```
"{ key1: {-1.2},\r\n key2: \"http://dummyimage.com/600x400/7190d6/fff.png\", key3: '3', key4: true }".match(/(\w+)(:)\s*(?='|"|[0-9+\-.]+|true|false|\[|{)/gi);
```

In this case, it matches only a word with ":", a possible space, then looks ahead for the next character to be a quote, value, array bracket, or object bracket, before accepting it. Certainly not fool proof in all cases.

Comment: thanks, that gets me closer. Unfortunately that won't work either since values could be other objects or arrays.

Comment: Thanks! It got me close enough: Here is how I tweaked it: ```(/([\w]+)(:)\s*(?='|"|[0-9+\-.]+|true|false|\[|{)/gi```

Comment: Why `[\w]+`? it's redundant. `\w+` is fine.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. However, you do need the ```(:)```

Comment: In full this is working: ```str.replace((/(\w+)(:)\s*(?='|"|[0-9+\-.]+|true|false|\[|{)/gi), "\"$1\"$2");```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this may be to use `eval` but using this function has a lot of implications in term of security, performance and debugability http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/

```
var json = '{key1: "Value 1", key2: "http://dummyimage.com/600x400/7190d6/fff.png"}';
eval('var jsonObject = ' + json);
json = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Your choice of variable names is a bit irritating. Nothing about this has anything to do with JSON. (I'm afraid it will confuse future readers less familiar with this topic)

Comment: I understand your point @FelixKling, what do you suggest as variable names ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have good alternatives. `data` and `obj` come to mind, but they only slightly better ;) I guess if knew what the data was about, we could come up with something better.

Comment: This may be a decent answer, assuming the input is coming from a safe source and doesn't modify external state at all. Unfortunately, we have no idea if this is the case or not.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this happens because you are making a global replacement. Since your "keyX:" is the first section of your strings and is also what you want to replace then try:

```
str.replace((/([\w]+)(:)), "\"$1\"$2")
```

Comment: sorry, did you add the "/" that was missing?